# How to read excel document containing hyperlinks

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

While reading excel document using apache poi API, I got following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A sheet hyperlink must either have a location, or a relationship. Found:
<xml-fragment ref="C1271" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing" xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac"/>
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFHyperlink.<init>(XSSFHyperlink.java:72)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.initHyperlinks(XSSFSheet.java:182)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:139)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:222)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:200)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:172)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:63)
at com.gepower.mdcatalog.test.Test.main(Test.java:34)
```

It's working fine if I manually remove that hyperlink from excel sheet...so my question is that possible to read excel sheet having hyperlink ?or is there any way to remove that hyperlink using java code itself..
Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code where you got this exception. Are you just getting it when reading any cell having hyperlink or something else.

Comment: I am not able to create simple instance of workbook if excel sheet has a hyperlink...here is code..File inputFile = new File("C:\\test.xlsx");
  InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
XSSFWorkbook book=  (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(inputstream);

Comment: I have used the excel with hyperlink many times, no matter with/without Hyperlink. It seems there must be any other issue. However I have updated my answer please check its working on your end or not.

Comment: What does Excel show the problematic hyperlink to be pointing to?

Comment: Hi Gan, I am also facing the same issue.. How did you resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Load and get the hyperlink address of any cell you need to `getHyperlink` of that cell. You can use following:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(FilePath));
Sheet TestSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Cell cell = TestSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
Hyperlink linkAddress = cell.getHyperlink();
if(linkAddress != null){
    System.out.println(linkAddress .getAddress());
}
```